# Explain the Verifiable Encryption (Camenisch-Shoup) process

Tags: verifiable-encryption

There are three entities: the *user* (prover), *the verifier*, and the *auditor*. The user sends a message to the verifier encrypted using the public key of the auditor. The goal of the user is to convince the verifier that the message is encrypted using the public key of the auditor using zero knowledge proof. Can you explain to me how to accomplish it using the verifiable encryption ([Camenisch-Shoup](https://www.shoup.net/papers/verenc.pdf)) process?